# Apple iOS Distribution Certificate

Tags: ios, certificate

I have an enterprise account for developing iOS apps which expires on the 23rd January 2018.

My iOS Distrubution certificate runs out on July 5th 2017.

In the run up to the Distribution certificate expiring should I:

a. Revoke the certifictate and create a new one
b. Just create a new certificate and let the current one expire

I find the management of Apple iOS certificate very confusing when I read the offical Apple documentation.

Any advice would be great.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't confuse the expiration of your enterprise account with the expiration of the distribution certificate. They are completely separate events.

You enterprise apps signed with your distribution certificate will expire on July 5 (regardless of the state of your enterprise account) and the app will need to be re-released, signed with a new certificate on or before that date.

I assume you will be renewing your enterprise development account, and at some time before July 5 you should release a new version of the enterprise app sign with a new distribution certificate.

As a side note, enterprise certificates are the most powerful certificates that Apple issues. They allow your code to run on any iOS device without the need for Apple to review and re-sign the app. Treat these certificates carefully.

Comment: many thanks for your reply, that cleared up what I have read. Again, many thanks.